# How to replace items in a list in JS after using .pop()?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a list and I pick elements from the list using .pop(). However, I don't want the list to be exhaustive i.e. I want the original list to remain unchanged but want to pick an element from the list using .pop() or .shift()

```
var list = [1,2,3,4]
list.pop()
```

Is there any way to do that?
Thank you!

Comment: why? take another approach ...

Comment: I want to pick an element on random from a list without using a loop. Any approach to do that?